# Is there a way to have 2 windows working like 2 "fake" monitors?

Tags: multiple-monitors

So I am trying to build a self-driving program for a game "Euro truck simulator". I think it would be helpful if I have two cameras in-game working as a stereo vision system. I already found a way to configure different camera positions in-game for dual monitors, the only problem being I don't have that many monitors. So is there a software that allows me to have "fake" monitors, each monitor can show up as a small window on my real monitors?